# Java For Loop conditional test

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm sure this is a very basic question but having trouble understanding why the below FOR loop works?

The code below brings back a set number of Primes and works as it should.  I understand the whole math reasoning behind using square root, however my issue is more with the conditional part of the FOR statement.

The first argument that is fed into `isPrime()` to check is 2 which of course is Prime.  The first `isPrime()` gets the square root of 2 which is ~ 1.4.
At this point, I get confused.  Starting at i = 2 which is obviously > 1.4  so than the starting condition of i <= root (ie 2 <= 1.4) has NOT been met. The `IF` statement should not run and it *should* return no result, but it does.

It doesn't seem to me like I should get any result back until I get to 5 because 2 is also > than the square root of 3.  I'm obviously not understating either the initialization or conditional aspect of the `FOR` statement here?  Can someone please help me with the logic?

```
class BooleanTest{
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
            int quantity = 10;
            int numPrimes = 0;                
            int candidate = 2;  //starting prime #
            System.out.println("First " + quantity + " primes:");
            while (numPrimes < quantity) {
                if (isPrime(candidate)) {   //if isPrime Method true
                    System.out.println(candidate);
                    numPrimes++;
                }
                candidate++;                
            }
    }      

    public static boolean isPrime(int checkNumber) {
        double root = Math.sqrt(checkNumber);  //get square root of candidate
        for (int i = 2; i <= root; i++) {  
            if (checkNumber % i == 0) { //if remainder of candidate/i = 0
            return false;  //because candidate is not prime.  has factor other than 1 and self.
        }

        return true;
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For inputs 1, 2, 3 the loop will not execute at all, indeed. As a result, the `return false` statement in the body of the loop will not be executed as well. Instead the `return true` statement right after the loop will get executed and the result of the method call will be `true` for these inputs.

The first number for which the loop will execute is 4 and the method will correctly return `false` as 4 is divideable by 2.

Fixing the indentation of the code makes this behavior a bit easier to see:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int checkNumber) {
    double root = Math.sqrt(checkNumber); //get square root of candidate
    for (int i = 2; i <= root; i++) {  
        if (checkNumber % i == 0) { //if remainder of candidate/i = 0
            return false; //because candidate is not prime.  has factor other than 1 and self.
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sebastian! So putting the return true outside of the for-loop but still within the method body makes the boolean method "default" to true even if the for-loop is never initiated.  That makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`root` is not initialized to `sqrt(2)`, it's initialized to `sqrt(checkNumber)`, which would be larger than 2 for most inputs. Therefore your `So than the starting condition of i <= root (ie 2 <= 1.4) has NOT been met so then the IF statement should not run and I would get no result back` assumption is false.